# How to get a specific value from a JSON response - Python

Tags: python, json, ssl, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

I am starting to work with python and now I am trying to retrieve some values from a REST, however I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\DESKTOP\test_check\check_securityPrices.py", line 69, in <module>
    jsonPath = r["assetPricing"]["instrumentId"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

this is the JSON response that I get:

```
[{
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001380992',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001380992',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 141.96875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 142.054687,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 142.140625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 141.984375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 141.984375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 143.569973,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 143.65591,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 143.741848,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 141.953125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 142.039063,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 142.125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001380993',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001380993',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 131.546875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.640625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.734375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.570312,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.570312,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.995245,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.081182,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.16712,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.546875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.632813,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.71875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001380994',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001380994',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 120.9375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.03125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 120.953125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 120.953125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 122.076766,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 122.162704,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 122.248641,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 120.921875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.007813,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.09375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001380995',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001380995',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 118.765625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 118.851562,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 118.9375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 118.773437,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 118.773437,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 119.858696,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 119.952446,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 120.046196,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 118.75,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 118.84375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 118.9375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001380996',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001380996',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 114.3125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.398437,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.484375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.328125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.328125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.641304,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.727242,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.813179,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.3125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.398438,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.484375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001380997',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001380997',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 121.140625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.234375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.328125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.171875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.171875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.514266,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.600204,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.686141,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.140625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.226563,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 121.3125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001380999',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001380999',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 114.25,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.34375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.4375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.265625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.265625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 115.250679,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 115.344429,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 115.438179,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.234375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.328125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 114.421875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001381000',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001381000',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 132.828125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.90625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.984375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.851562,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.851562,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 134.19837,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 134.276495,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 134.35462,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.8125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.890625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 132.96875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001381004',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001381004',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 130.734375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 130.8125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 130.890625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 130.765625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 130.765625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.167799,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.238111,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 131.308424,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 130.734375,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 130.804688,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 130.875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}, {
    '_fpmlVersion': '5-6',
    'header': {
        'messageType': 'PrevDayCloseBond',
        'sendTo': [{
            '#value': 'Anvil'
        }],
        'creationTimestamp': '2021-09-27T06:00:00.000Z'
    },
    'm:asOfDate': {
        '#value': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    },
    '_xmlns': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting',
    '_xmlns:m': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm',
    '_xmlns:mhi': 'urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi',
    '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    '_xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd',
    'm:assetPricing': [{
        'm:pricingSource': [{
            '#value': 'LON-XEN-BBG'
        }, {
            '#value': 'BGN',
            '_pricingSourceScheme': 'mizuho:bloomberg-source'
        }],
        'm:instrumentId': [{
            '#value': '100001381005',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'
        }, {
            '#value': '100001381005',
            '_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhsa:instrument-id'
        }],
        'm:currency': {
            '#value': 'USD'
        },
        'm:price': [{
            'value': 126.28125,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 126.351562,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 126.421875,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 126.304687,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Closing Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 126.304687,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Snap Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 127.512908,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 127.58322,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 127.653533,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Dirty Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 126.265625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Bid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 126.335938,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Mid Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }, {
            'value': 126.40625,
            'measureType': {
                '#value': 'Clean Offer Price',
                '_assetMeasureScheme': 'mizuho:price-type'
            }
        }],
        'm:pricingDate': '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'
    }]
}]
```

This is my code so far.

```
# # Request to get the instrumentID from CDW
listInstrumentID = []
securityPricesCDW = f"https://svc-uat-cdw/cdw/securityPrices/{dateinplay}?limit=10"

r = requests.get(securityPricesCDW).json()

# print(r)
jsonPath = parse("$..'m:assetPricing'[*].'m:pricingSource'[*].'m:instrumentId'[*].'#value'")

for match in jsonPath.find(r):
    print(f"match id: {match.value}")
   thisdict = match.value
   listInstrumentID.append(thisdict)
```

Anyway, if someone can help me get all the value of Array of Object 'instrumentId' **'m:instrumentId': [{
'#value': '100001380992',
'_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'**

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Looks like you are mixing XML with json. You show XML document and the code is json oriented...

Comment: this is a response I received from a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below (assuming `data` is the list of dicts from the post)

```
ids = [x['m:assetPricing'][0]['m:instrumentId'][0]['#value'] for x in data]
print(ids)
```

output

```
['100001380992', '100001380993', '100001380994', '100001380995', '100001380996', '100001380997', '100001380999', '100001381000', '100001381004', '100001381005']
```

Comment: If there's just one element, why not to use `.find()`?

Comment: What if in the actual document there will be 123 elements?

Comment: thanks for the reply, however this is not an xml file. It is a response from a request I made.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: no, I updated the response. I'm working with a JSON

Comment: @BrunoLorena Answer was modified in order to support the list of dicts

Comment: Isn't it what you currently get?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

root = ElementTree.parse(url_of_your_file).getroot()

for found in root.findall("m:assetPricing")
    print(found.find("m:instrumentId").text)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).